# Converting Mp3 to Wav with User Input Issue

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I'm trying to take user input of path and file format and convert all the files in the specified path, to wav files using the Pydub module. I receive this error:

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pydub/audio_segment.py", line 342, in from_file

raise CouldntDecodeError("Decoding failed. ffmpeg returned error code: {0}".format(retcode))
pydub.exceptions.CouldntDecodeError: Decoding failed. ffmpeg returned error code: 1

```
import os
import glob
from pydub import AudioSegment



def AudioCon():
    audio_dir = input('Enter the path of the audio to convert : ')
    extension = input('Enter Audio File Format')
    ex = ('*.' + extension)
    os.chdir(audio_dir)
    return convertphase(audio_dir,ex)


def convertphase(audio_dir,ex):
    for x in ex:
        for Audio in glob.glob(ex):
            wav_filename = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(Audio))[0] + '.wav'
            AudioSegment.from_file(Audio).export(wav_filename, format='wav')




AudioCon()
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem. If I find a solution I'll be sure to post an answer!

Comment: @Eamonn Have you found it !!